# Update column in postgreSQL first letter capital

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

How to update column in postgreSQL and set only first character capital?

Eg.  TEST   --->    Test

I tried, but not working

```
UPDATE car SET carName=UPPER(LEFT(carName,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(carName,2,LEN(carName)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should not be a problem:

```
postgres=# select * from f10;
+--------+
|   a    |
+--------+
| nazdar |
+--------+
(1 row)

postgres=# update f10 set a = upper(substring(a from 1 for 1)) || lower(substring(a from 2));
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from f10;
+--------+
|   a    |
+--------+
| Nazdar |
+--------+
(1 row)
```

Maybe you can use [`initcap`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) functions too:

```
postgres=# select initcap('hello world');
+-------------+
|   initcap   |
+-------------+
| Hello World |
+-------------+
(1 row)
```